# rspec rails testing: how can I force ActiveJob job's to run inline for certain tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-activejob

I would like my background jobs to run inline for certain marked tests.  I can do it by wrapping the test with `perform_enqueued do` but I'd like to just be able to tag them with metadata and it happens automatically, if possible.

I've tried the following:

```
it "does everything in the job too", perform_enqueued: true do
end

config.around(:each) do |example|
  if example.metadata[:perform_enqueued]
    perform_enqueued_jobs do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

but it results in an error:

```
undefined method `perform_enqueued_jobs=' for ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::InlineAdapter:Class
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to set your adapter for tests to `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter` which responds to `.perform_enqueued_jobs =`. You can do that on your `spec/rails_helper.rb` file:

```
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
```

Answer (score 11):

In your `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper
end
```

Or in your test:

```
context "when jobs are executed" do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  # ...
end
```

Then in your tests:

```
perform_enqueued_jobs do
  example.run
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to use `InlineAdapter` in tests? — `ActiveJob::TestHelper` won't let you!

I see that you were trying to use `InlineAdapter`...

I had the same desire — to use the `InlineAdapter` in all my tests.

Unfortunately — at least for RSpec request tests (ActionDispatch integration tests) — `ActiveJob::TestHelper` gets automatically included into the test context, and it seems to *force* you to use `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter` rather than `InlineAdapter`.

`gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb` has all this:

```rb
    ActiveJob::Base.include(TestQueueAdapter)

    def before_setup # :nodoc:
      test_adapter = queue_adapter_for_test

      queue_adapter_changed_jobs.each do |klass|
        klass.enable_test_adapter(test_adapter)
      end

      clear_enqueued_jobs
      clear_performed_jobs
      super
    end

    def after_teardown # :nodoc:
      super

      queue_adapter_changed_jobs.each { |klass| klass.disable_test_adapter }
    end

    # Specifies the queue adapter to use with all Active Job test helpers.
    #
    # Returns an instance of the queue adapter and defaults to
    # ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter.
    #
    # Note: The adapter provided by this method must provide some additional
    # methods from those expected of a standard ActiveJob::QueueAdapter
    # in order to be used with the active job test helpers. Refer to
    # ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter.
    def queue_adapter_for_test
      ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter.new
    end
```

which causes it to completely *ignore* any `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline` configuration you might have (because it *overrides* the `queue_adapter` `class_attribute`).

I even tried overriding `queue_adapter_for_test`:

```
    def queue_adapter_for_test
      ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::InlineAdapter.new
    end
```

but it *still* doesn't work, because `InlineAdapter` doesn't define `enqueued_jobs` and we get this:

```rb
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `enqueued_jobs' for #<ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::InlineAdapter:0x00007f7efcce6580>
       Did you mean?  enqueue
     # gems/3.1.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb:9:in `enqueued_jobs'
     # gems/3.1.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb:641:in `clear_enqueued_jobs'
     # gems/3.1.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb:46:in `before_setup'
```

In conclusion... There's no *supported* way to use `InlineAdapter`
anywhere that `ActiveJob::TestHelper` is included (such as request tests). But there are always workarounds...

### Workaround #1: Override `enqueued_jobs`, etc. to avoid getting errors

Assuming you're using RSpec, you can add a `spec/support/active_job.rb` that does this:

```rb
# Override some things from ActiveJob::TestHelper (which gets included automatically by RSpec in
# request tests) so that we can use InlineAdapter instead of TestAdapter and don't have to manually
# call perform_enqueued_jobs any time we have jobs that get enqueued — InlineAdapter automatically
# runs the job immediately (synchronously). See
# https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html.
module UseInlineQueueAdapter
  def queue_adapter_for_test
    ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::InlineAdapter.new
  end

  def enqueued_jobs
    if queue_adapter.respond_to?(__callee__)
      super
    else
      []
    end
  end

  def performed_jobs
    if queue_adapter.respond_to?(__callee__)
      super
    else
      []
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include UseInlineQueueAdapter
end
```

### Your specific question — only for certain, marked tests

In my case, I was happy just using inline adapter for *all* tests...

But it sounds like you would like the ability to only use it for *some* tests, which you mark with metadata.

It seems like that shouldn't be much harder. It seems like all you would have to do is add a conditional to the `queue_adapter_for_test` method that you override:

```rb
  def queue_adapter_for_test
    if example.metadata[:inline_jobs]
      ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::InlineAdapter.new
    else
      ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter.new
    end
  end
```

### Workaround #2: Just use `TestAdapter` like it wants you to

Since `perform_enqueued_jobs` causes any jobs enqueued during the duration of the block to be performed immediately ("inline"), what you had should have worked fine too — but only if you leave `queue_adapter` set to `TestAdapter` (`:test`):

```rb
config.around(:each) do |example|
  if example.metadata[:perform_enqueued]
    perform_enqueued_jobs do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

The other reason why it didn't work for you is because `around(:each)` gets run *before* `before(:each)`. So even though `ActiveJob::TestHelper` automatically changes the queue adapter to `TestAdapter` — it does so from a `before(:each)` (technically a `before_setup` callback). So at the point where your `around(:each)` is calling `perform_enqueued_jobs`, the `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter` should still be however it was configured in your configuration.

Presumably you have something like `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline` in your `config/environments/test.rb`? As other answers have noted, you'll have to change that to `:test` instead if you want your approach to work.

Because, as the error points out, `InlineAdapter` has no concept of `enqueued_jobs` — and correspondingly, no method named `perform_enqueued_jobs` defined.

Here's what I came up with, which seems to work:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(Module.new do
    # Without this, the perform_enqueued_jobs block below has no effect, because it sets
    # perform_enqueued_jobs on ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter, yet
    # ActiveJob::TestHelper#queue_adapter_for_test by default instantiates a _new_
    # ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter.new (this happens in a before(:example)), whose
    # perform_enqueued_jobs attribute would of course still have the default value of nil.
    def queue_adapter_for_test
      if ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.is_a?(ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter)
        ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end)

  config.around do |example|
    if example.metadata[:perform_enqueued_jobs]
      perform_enqueued_jobs do
        example.run
      end
    else
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can go ahead and annotate any example groups or examples where you want enqueued jobs to be performed immediately!

```rb
it "performs the job immediately as soon as enqueued", :perform_enqueued_jobs do
  # ...
end
```

Having tried both of these workarounds, I would now recommend the second one, as it's more flexible, and still lets you do async enqueuing in any tests that need it, but lets you switch to inline performing when you can get away with that simpler option...