# How to write rspec mock for method that calls a mailer in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to test a mailer method from my endpoint which looks like this:

```
ConfirmationMailer.send_email(email).deliver_later
```

And the corresponding spec looks like this:

```
let(:confirmation_mailer_stub) { instance_double ConfirmationMailer }

before do
  allow(ConfirmationMailer).to receive(:send_email)
end

it 'sends confirmation email' do
  call_endpoint
  expect(confirmation_mailer_stub).to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
end
```

But I've got an error:

> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `deliver_later' for nil:NilClass

The `send_email` method is quite simple:

```
def send_email(email)
  mail(to: email, cc: email)
end
```

How can I test this method?

Comment: Sounds like you may have misunderstood how test doubles and mocking work. If you're providing a double for an object, you can't expect it to do any of its original functions. Can you show the code you're testing in full, and the test you've written in full?

Answer (score 0):

You stubbed `send_email` in `ConfirmationMailer` without defining any value to be returned:

```
before do
  allow(ConfirmationMailer).to receive(:send_email)
end
```

You need to define a value returned by the stubbed method (with `#and_return`) or [call original](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation):
before do
  allow(ConfirmationMailer).to receive(:send_email).and_call_original
end

That said, I think it's not the best way to test if email is sent. Better use the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284748/580346):
configure `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` and assert on global array `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`.

Comment: After adding `and_call_original` I've got  different error -> ```expected `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count` to have changed by 1, but was not given a block```

Comment: _Either_ use stubbing _or_ check deliveries count. Don't do both.

Comment: So how my test should looks like? is it ```expect{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.to change.by(1)``` without stubbing?

Comment: Configure AJ correctly :https://stackoverflow.com/a/39712145/580346